# Angular.js ng-show and directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" ng-controller="modal-ctrl" ng-show="showModal" execute-on-esc>
```

Angular.js app:

```
app.controller('modal-ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = true;
});

app.directive('executeOnEsc', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope) {
            return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
                event.which === 27? scope.showModal = false : false;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Everything works well, $scope.showModal chages to false, but ng-show doesn't respond to this change. Why? Console.log shows that $scope.showModal changes.
Where's the problem?

Comment: When did you console.log the value of showModal?

Comment: return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
                event.which === 27? scope.showModal = false : false;
                console.log(scope.showModal);
});

Different roots, right?

Comment: replace ng-show with ng-hide just to check the display?

Comment: if it works ,replace ng-show="!showModal"

Comment: Thanks, Naga Sai but the question have been answered by Patrick Evans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
    event.which === 27? scope.showModal = false : 
});
```

You are creating an event listener, this listener executes outside of an angular digest cycle. As such you have to tell angular to start a new digest cycle in order for the changes to be picked up. You can use [scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to do this:

```
return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
    scope.$apply(function(){
        event.which === 27? scope.showModal = false : 
    });
});
```

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('modal-ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showModal = true;
});

app.directive('executeOnEsc', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope) {
      return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          event.which === 27 ? scope.showModal = false : false;
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="modal-dialog" ng-controller="modal-ctrl" ng-show="showModal" execute-on-esc>
    My Modal
  </div>
</div>
```